# Hide layout for particular time

Tags: java, android, time, timepicker

I am building app.in that I want to hide my layout from 8 Am to 12 Am. I tried using thread and asynctask but I don't understand how to give time period between 8 to 12.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
     <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/vegitables"
            app:civ_border_color="#80000000"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Veg :"
            android:textColor="#F00"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to set a function to hide this layout between 8-12 Am (using checking current time) and call it in `onResume()` of your activity hosting this layout.

Comment: `if(getNow is between 8am and 12am) { layout.hide() }else{ layout.show()}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int currentHour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
if(currentHour >=7 && currentHour <= 11)
    rootLayoutReference.setVisibility(View.GONE);
else
    rootLayoutReference.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: `HOUR_OF_DAY` isn't zero-based. You can just use 8 and 12.

Comment: i made little change in that because (Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) it give me hour as 24 so i put if(currentHour>=8 && currentHour<=23){view.setClickable(false)}

Answer (score 0):

First of all 12 AM means midnight, while 12 PM means noon. I assumed you meant noon, but this solution can be easily changed to any time boundaries.

You can add following to your Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Handler handler;
    private View layout;
    private Runnable updateVisibilityCallback;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        updateVisibilityCallback = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateTextVisibility();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        updateTextVisibility();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        handler.removeCallbacks(updateVisibilityCallback);
    }

    private void updateTextVisibility() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        if (8 <= hour && hour <= 11) {
            layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        handler.postDelayed(updateVisibilityCallback, getVisibilityUpdateDelay());
    }

    private long getVisibilityUpdateDelay() {
        Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        Calendar nextUpdate = Calendar.getInstance();
        nextUpdate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        nextUpdate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        nextUpdate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        if (hour < 8) {
            nextUpdate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        } else if (hour < 12) {
            nextUpdate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        } else {
            nextUpdate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            nextUpdate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        }

        return nextUpdate.getTimeInMillis() - rightNow.getTimeInMillis();
    }
}
```

Every time when the Activity becomes visible to a user (in `onResume`) you check the time and update the visibility of the layout. Moreover you keep track when the next update should happen - you calculate the delay to either 8:00 or 12:00 and post a `Runnable` using a `Handler`. Whenever your user stops focusing on the activity you clear the callback.